How do you figure out which app or apps correspond to a developer's name in the login items section of System Settings?
In the General / Login Items section of System Settings, many of the listings there are not for a specific application but rather a developer, and as such it lists the name of the developer. Very often it's not obvious which apps on your computer are by that developer, especially if it's just a person's name. I don't know why Apple decided to do things in such a way that's bound to be confusing for users and hostile towards developers, but I digress.
Is there a convenient way of discovering which app or apps correspond to that developer that are being granted permission to have login items?
(Note: I do understand under the hood how this works, which is that login items permissions are granted based on the developer's certificate rather than to a specific application, so in theory one could write an elaborate script that scans through the whole computer, checks the signature of every app and its associated team ID, and finds the ones whose team ID corresponds to the name listed in Login Items. But that would be an inconvenient way to figure this out. I'm hoping there's something more sensible.)
